# How to show a "loading" buttonless AlertView while performing REST requests

Tags: objective-c, rest, uialertview

I'm trying to do the following:

1. show a buttonless UIAlertView showing a "Loading" message
2. perform a REST request like

   ```
   currentPlans = [RestUtils restSynchnonousCall:url
                                 usingMethod:@"GET"
                                    withBody:nil];
   ```
3. dismissing the UIAlertView
4. `return currentPlans`

I've looked for `dispatch_async` pattern, I've also looked at this thread [UIAlertView starts to show, screen dims, but it doesn't pop up until it's too late!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185223/uialertview-starts-to-show-screen-dims-but-it-doesnt-pop-up-until-its-too-lat) without understanding so much... :(

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Alert view is supposed to inform something that user can cancel or ask for simple things like yes/no. For loading/connecting I suggest to use `UIActivityIndicator`. Please note that changing the behavior of standard components does not comply with the human interface guidelines. User should be able to dismiss an alert view on his/her wish.

Answer (score 0):

Ivan I think you need to use Activity Indicator for "Loading" process.
But if you like to use button less alertview then ,use this code:
UIAlertView *loadingAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading...." 
                                                                 message:nil
                                                                delegate:nil
                                                                   cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];

```
        [loadingAlert show];
        [loadingAlert release];
```

When ever your request is done....write this code in that delegate method:
            [loadingAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
This code automatically terminate your alertview.
**loadingAlert must be defined inside .h file.